# Determine where a gmail add-on is running

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm developing an add-on for gmail and I'd like it to show different texts depending on whether it's running on the browser or on the android app, but I don't know if it's possible.

I've tried using `HtmlService.getUserAgent()` and the deprecated `UiApp.getUserAgent()`, but both of them return `null`; and I haven't found any other possibilities on the documentation.

Can anyone help on this? Thanks!

Comment: `HtmlService.getUserAgent()` do returns the required details. Provide some code to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The function provided as `onTriggerFunction` of the `appsscript.json` file has an `event` parameter with a `clientPlatform` property that can be either `'web'` or `'android'`.